# Magit - Unable to commit

Tags: magit, git

Magit is unable to commit anything is giving the following message

> 1 c:/cygwin64/bin/git.exe … commit -- Waiting for Emacs...
>
> *ERROR*: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nilerror: There was a problem with the editor '"c:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Emacs/emacs-24.5/bin/emacsclient.exe"'. Please supply the
>   message using either -m or -F option.

How do I pass the -m and -F option?

platform - Windows 8
Emacs - 24.5.1
installed magit from package manager.

I wanted to use cygwin with emacs, having set that, cygwin didnt see the windows git properly - hence I installed git for cygwin. Probably that's causing some issue? In my *exec-path* I have the path of cygwin-git. I am new to magit so help would be appriciated and also let me know if I can provide with more information.

EDIT : Both the git installation work properly - I tried some test commit from and cygwin and cmdprompt and I am able to commit normally.

Comment: All I can say: this is not about passing `-m` or `-F` options, that message is a side effect of another problem. You'd probably get more meaningful information if you did `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` before trying to commit.

Comment: Do *not* mix Cygwin and Windows programs unless you're ready for a world of hurt. If you want to use Emacs from Cygwin, install the `emacs-w32` package and use that.

Comment: I have everything working except magit. Toggling debug on error does nothing. I get no information in message buffer.  Any idea on why emacs isn't able to commit?

Comment: What magit version are you using? The latest release contains some kludges for cygwin, which should prevent this.

Comment: M-x magit-version gives me - Magit 20150729.518, Git 2.4.5, Emacs 24.5.1
I uninstalled and reinstalled the package from Emacs package manager. In elpa the latest version is  20150729.518

Comment: OP asked the same question in three different places. I am responding here: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2127. Therefore this issue is a duplicate, but not of another issue on this site, so I cannot give "it's a duplicate" as the closing reason. (Is there a way to give an arbitrary closing reason?)

Comment: @tarsius In this situation, the correct thing to do is post an answer here. I think just copy-pasting your reply to the github issue would be plenty enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted multiple times because I thought github repo was *only* for feature request and also tried the chat but there was no activity.

Anyway the problem seem to be proper initialization and setup of cygwin on windows. I tried the setup suggested by *benquike* in https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1318 -- Restating it here.

> 1. Download cygwin-mount.el( For links go the link above or replace the @ with : http@//emacswiki.org/emacs/cygwin-mount.el) to
>      somewhere
> 2. download setup-cygwin.el(http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/setup-cygwin.el) to
>      somewhere
> 3. in your init.el(or .emacs),add the following

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "where you placed cygwin-mount.el and setup-cygwin.el")
(require 'setup-cygwin)
```

Only problem seem to be that you cannot place the .el files mentioned above in your .emacs.d folder but instead place it in a subdirectory. (As with the new version of Emacs they are "discouraging" that)

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#!/bin/dash -e
if [ "${1#/}" != "$1" ]
then k=$(cygpath -w "$1")
elif [ "$#" != 0 ]
then k=$1
fi
exec emacsclient ${k+"$k"}
```

1. If no path, pass no path
2. If path is empty, pass empty path
3. If path is relative, pass as is
4. If path is absolute, convert to Windows format

Then I set these variables:

```sh
export EDITOR=emacsclient.sh
export GIT_EDITOR='dash /usr/local/bin/emacsclient.sh'
```

1. EDITOR allows script to work with Git
2. GIT_EDITOR allows script to work with [Hub commands](//hub.github.com)

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/tree/6a614d4/notepad2)